# What is the meaning difference between these sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-tense, tense-agreement

> Two days before the Eden Garden hosts the match, the celebrations are already on.
>
> Two days before the Eden Garden is hosting the match, the celebrations are already on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple present marks the action as a moment or point in time, and the action can be represented by an X.

The progressive depicts the action of *to host* as having duration. It goes on for some time. It can be represented by ~~~~~~~~~~.

Usually it also means limited duration. Eden Garden won't always be hosting the match. I won't always *be writing* this answer

In addition, the present progressive is used to indicate an action *in progress*. I am currently *writing this answer*.

Thus, there is some disconnect between saying *is hosting* (which can mean *in the process of hosting*) and the adverbial *two days before*. Thus, in many contexts it will be much more natural to use the simple present.

But, since the celebrations have already started and are in progress, it would be natural to say

> Two days before the Eden Garden hosts  the match, the celebrations are already going on.

(But simple *are on* or, more to my liking *are underway*, is preferable to the above, which is meant to illustrate the sense of the progressive.)

Unless you have a reason to represent *to host* as having duration, having limited duration, and perhaps being in progress at the moment of speaking, I'd use the simple present, especially in this sentence.

Have you ever interacted with native speakers and paid attention to their use of present progressive? Try it, it might prove helpful and be more intuitive than trying to remember an answer that someone gives you, which you'll probably forget.

Comment: Please consider reading [Not so fast–when should I accept my answer?](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)